# Converting Date to other format in C#

Tags: date

Can any one suggest me the following:
 i> how to convert 3/12/2010 10:15 to the format Mar 12, 2010 10:15 in c#.
 ii> how to remove time part out of it(i.e after the conversion i want Mar 12, 2010

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nimesh,

The String.Format function should be able to accommodate your needs (updated to reflect my comment):

```
string inputString = "03/12/2012";
DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
try {
    dt = DateTime.Parse(inputString);    
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle the exception however you like.
    return;
}
string formattedDate = String.Format("{0:MMM d, yyyy}", dt);
```

To avoid the above, check out TryParse:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx

You can format it in lots of ways:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: Hi mikey ,thanks for the quick response.Here input date is a string and not Date Time Object.i.e  3/12/2010 10:15 is a string which as to be converted to other format.

Comment: I'd first parse the input string as a date, then do the above with it.  DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(inputString); string formattedDate... etc.  Wrap the Parse in a try/catch though to make sure the input string is really a date that is parse-able.

Comment: TryParse is another alternative  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.Parse(...) to parse the input string into a DateTime object, and then use Format to make the string as posted by mikey.